# How many intersections will two binary numbers have for a certain hamming distance?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, binary

Numerically, say I have two numbers: 00000 and 11000

Then I find out each of their HD=2 values:

For **00000** the list is:

> 5C2 possibilities

For **11000** the list is:

> 5C2 possibilities

My questions is how do I know the number of intersected binary numbers?

In this case, they are **6**   [01001, 01010, 01100, ...      10100]

Answer (score 1):

Form the XOR of the two numbers. There can only be intersections if it has $0$, $2$ or $4$ ones. If it has $0$ ones, we need to modify both strings at the same two arbitrary bits, so the number of intersections is $\binom n2$, where $n$ is the length of the strings. If it has $4$ ones, we can choose $2$ bits at which to modify the one string and then modify the other string at the other two, so there are $\binom42=6$ intersections. If it has $2$ ones (as in your case), we can choose one of the two at which to modify the one string, modify the other string at the other, and then choose one more bit at which to modify both, so here we have $2(n-2)$ intersections (which in your case also comes out to $6$).

Comment: Sorry, can I ask you to elaborate on how you know there can be intersections only when there are 0, 2, or 4 ones? I am not getting what 'it' is.

Comment: @zaki: If there are more than $4$ differences between the strings, you can't get them to match by changing $2\cdot2=4$ bits. If there's an odd number of differences, you can't get them to match by changing an even number of bits.

Comment: Sorry I've still can't figure out another thing (I am bad at these type of problems): when you talk about 4 ones, let's say I have 00000 and 11110 ...then you say I can choose 2 bits to modify one and modify another 2 at the other so I get 11000 for both...then how do you conclude to 4C2 from there. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @zaki: There are $4$ bits to match. $2$ of them must be modified in one string, the other $2$ in the other. There are $\binom42$ ways to choose the $2$ that we modify in the one string. That already determines the other $2$ that we then need to modify in the other string, so there are no further choices.

Comment: Thank you again. Now I get it. As for the last case, what would the formula be in terms of Combinations like the way you expressed the intersections for 4 ones.. Can't it be generalized? 

Also, I understand the analysis but the the 2 ( n - 2 ) intersection formula that follows I don't get it :(

Comment: @zaki: Well, you can write it as $\binom21\binom{n-2}1$ if you prefer. You can choose $1$ of $2$ bits to modify in the one string, that's $\binom21$ choices; that already determines that you have to modify the other of the two bits in the other string. And then you can choose $1$ of the remaining $n-2$ bits to modify in both strings, that's $\binom{n-2}1$ choices. Since these choices are independent, you need to multiply their counts (according to the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)).

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. May I ask the number of intersection explanation for the same strings but when HD = 3 and 4 please? I seem to be muddling up the logics.

Comment: @zaki: For Hamming distance $3$, the XOR can have $0$, $2$, $4$ or $6$ ones. For $0$ ones, choose $3$ of $n$ bits to modify in both strings in $\binom n3$ ways. For $2$ ones, choose $1$ of them to modify in one string (and the other in the other) and $2$ of $n-2$ remaining bits to modify in both, for $\binom21\binom{n-2}2$ ways. For $4$ ones, choose $2$ of them to modify in one string (and the other $2$ in the other) and $1$ of $n-4$ remaining bits to modify in both, for $\binom42\binom{n-4}1$ ways. For $6$ ones, choose $3$ of them to modify in one string, for $\binom63$ ways.

Comment: @zaki: Generally, for Hamming distance $d$, the XOR can have any even number of ones from $0$ to $2d$, and if it has $2k$ ones, there are $\binom{2k}k\binom{n-2k}{d-k}$ intersections. I'll leave it to you to apply that to $d=4$ :-)

Comment: Sorry I dont know if I am dumbing down or what.. How can the XOR have 6 ones? The bits I am considering are 00000 and 11000. Altogether 5 bits each. 5 bits can have 6 ones? Also I always seem to be messing up the logic behind the XOR having 0, 2, 4 or 6 ones for HD=3?

Comment: @zaki: I wrote the general solution for arbitrary $n$. Of course there can be at most $n$ ones, so in your case with $n=5$, you can't have $6$ ones, that's true.

Comment: thank you very much..now I understand all the examples

Comment: Also if there are odd number of ones, not even as in 2k ones, what would be the final equations for intersections..if I may?

Comment: @zaki: Zero. If the strings differ in an odd number of bits, there's no way you can make them match by changing an even number of bits in each of them.

Comment: Yes. Sorry I mean I can also change odd number of bits i.e. HD=2 is not fixed and can vary by n. so I can change between HD=2,3,4,5

I understand that for 2 and 4 it is not possible; but for 3? So that's why I was wondering if there's any general equation for strings with odd number of bit difference and if I can make them match by changing odd number of bits.

Comment: @zaki: I'm afraid I don't follow you. I wrote down a full explicit solution for Hamming distance $3$ above. The Hamming distance between the strings and the intersections and the number of ones in the XOR of the strings are two different things.

Comment: Okay. Sorry for the previous message.

Hopefully this will me my last question.

I am trying to apply the formula to the following situations but they are not working/ I am not getting it:

1. For 000000 and 111100 (total # bits=6) ...the number of intersections when I calculate HD=2 for each of them.

2.For 00000 and 11100 (total # bits=5) ...the number of intersections when I calculate HD=3 for each of them.

3.For 00000 and 11100 (total # bits=5) ...the number of intersections when I calculate HD=5 for each of them.

Comment: @zaki: I don't see much point in continuing in this way. Why don't you write your calculations in those cases, and why you think they're wrong, and I can comment on that.

Comment: Using this formula, (2k k) (n−2k d−k) For 1. Because 2k = 4 bits difference between strings and k =2, and for second part, (n-2k)=6-4 =2, and d=k=2 hence I get (4 2 ) ( 2 0 ) =6 but it should be 8. Pretty sure I made a mistake somewhere :(

Comment: @zaki: No, $6$ is correct for that case. Why do you think it should be $8$?

Comment: oh thanks it should be 6 indeed.

For 2.  I am not being able to approach this problem because there are odd number of ones in XOR.

#3 is not necessary anymore.

Comment: @zaki: We seem to be talking past each other on the issue of odd numbers of ones. I've written several times now that there are zero intersection in this case, and why. If you don't engage with those arguments, I don't know what else to say about that.